# node js вывод запроса из mysql на html страницу

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

Здравствуйте, не могу реализовать вывод запроса из mysql на html страницу. В консоль все выводится хорошо, html страницу тоже создаю, все ок, но никак не могу реализовать вывод запроса на html страницу.
Ниже привожу код

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123456",
    database: 'databook'
});
connection.connect();
var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM books';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log(rows[i].id, rows[i].name, rows[i].bookname, rows[i].year);
    }
});
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function(req, res, rows) { 
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.write(
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'
        +'<head>'
        +'<meta charset="utf-8">'
        +'<title>Books</title>'
        +'</head>'
        +'<body>'
        +'<table>';)
    for (var i in rows) {
        res.write('<tr><td>'+rows[i].id+'</td><td>'+rows[i].name+'</td><td>'+rows[i].bookname+'</td><td>'+rows[i].year+'</td>');
    }
    res.write(
        +'</table>'
        +'</body>'
        +'</html>');
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337');
```

Comment: Отдельно код запроса в базу вижу, код ответа вебсервером вижу, а где попытка их соединить? Хотя бы неработающая. Чтоб мы поняли, что именно вы не поняли.

Comment: Добавил вывод в html страницу запроса из БД в цикле, там и происходит ошибка, не знаю как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отправить строку сформировав ее в том же цикле, что формирует вывод в консоль, перед этим создав переменную

```
var stroka = "";    
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i in rows) {
            stroka += '<tr><td>'+rows[i].id+'</td><td>'+rows[i].name+'</td><td>'+rows[i].bookname+'</td><td>'+rows[i].year+'</td></tr>';
        }
});
```

Затем где идет вывод странички вставляем между тегами `<table></table>` нашу строку

```
  res.write(
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'
        +'<head>'
        +'<meta charset="utf-8">'
        +'<title>Books</title>'
        +'</head>'
        +'<body>'
        +'<table>'
        +stroka
        +'</table>'
        +'</body>'
        +'</html>');
```

В остальном код остается прежним

Либо можно поместить цикл с запрос `connection.query` прямо в код `http.createServer` и генерировать каждый раз новую строчку, но обратите внимание, что res.end() и другие теги, которые идут после вывода запроса, также будут в `connection.query` после цикла, иначе таблица не выведется

```
http.createServer(function(req, res, rows) { 
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
        res.write(
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'
        +'<head>'
        +'<meta charset="utf-8">'
        +'<title>Books</title>'
        +'</head>'
        +'<body>'
        +'<table align="center" border="1px">'
        +'<h1 align="center">Книги</h1>');
        var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM books';
        var stroka = "";    
        connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            for (var i in rows) {
                stroka = '<tr><td>'+rows[i].id+'</td><td>'+rows[i].name+'</td><td>'+rows[i].bookname+'</td><td>'+rows[i].year+'</td></tr>';
                res.write(stroka);

            }
            res.write('</table>'
                +'</body>'
                +'</html>');
            res.end();
        });
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас rows

```
for (var i in rows) {
            res.write('<tr><td>'+rows[i].id+'</td><td>'+rows[i].name+'</td><td>'+rows[i].bookname+'</td><td>'+rows[i].year+'</td>');
        }
```

, будет undefined, вам надо объявить переменную

```
 var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM books';
        var findRows = []
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    findRows = rows

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log(rows[i].id, rows[i].name, rows[i].bookname, rows[i].year);
    }
});
```

Только скорее всего запрос к mysql и поиск в ней асинхронный и сервер не будет дожидаться окончания поиска. Делайте обертку async/await надо запросом и и потом уже отдавайте страничку

Comment: Новую переменную увидел, как сделать обертку не понял, подскажите пожалуйста как должен выглядть код в итоге.